# Creating graphics in bulk with minor variances

Tags: automation, script

I need to make 50-500 copies of a photo with a phone number printed over top of each. Each of the 50-500 copies needs to have a *different* colored font or font type for the phone number.

I have been using the iPhone app Phonto to create the graphics and have been saving them individually and then changing the font and saving again 500+ times.

Is there any way on any design program that I can change the phone number and save it with each of the 50 colors?

Each image needs to look similar to the one below, each with a different color/font combination. The photos can be saved to JPEG or PNG sized 612x612px.

[image]

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need to do this?

Comment: Also, you should add what you want it to look like and what format you want it in

Comment: @MarkMussler These are promotional graphics... I would need them to look similar to what I have just posted in my question.

Comment: I don't know what the final format needs to be but if these are on-screen graphics, this would be fairly easy to do with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a combination of svg graphics and either imagemagick or inkscape. And a bit of scripting

Make an svg template for the design, insert clear placeholders. When you have new values just run a string replacement on the values, save with a new name and then run imagemagick to convert it to png.

You will need some experience with programming tools to do this, but it's not difficult.